# Can anyone get the default ip using only netstat -rn, while, read, and cut command?

Tags: linux, networking, command, cut, netstat

As you can imagine, I should only use these commands to get the default IP of my virtual machine. netstat -rn gives the following output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination   Gateway        Genmask ...
0.0.0.0       138.248.123.23 ....
```

I need to get 138.248.123.23(this is a made up IP) but I cannot use awk or sed. I can get the third line of the output using while and read but I cannot extract it using cut command. I've tried `netstat -rn | cut -f2 -d$'\t'` but it didn't work...

Comment: I can't imagine anyone should use only those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use awk and sed?

Here is one more solution:

```
grep ^0.0.0.0 | tr -s " " | cut -f2 -d" "
```

The `-s` option turns strings of spaces into a single space.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I follow but this?

```
# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s25
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0

# netstat -rn | while read dest gw rest ; do [[ "${dest}" == "0.0.0.0" ]] && echo "${gw}" ; done
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: As you can see, there could be more default GWs :) Try `ip r s` and check *metric* (aka priority).

Answer (score 0):

Using just netstat and the shell, you can do

```
set -- $(netstat -rn)
shift 13
echo $1
```

but that is a bit fragile.

```
x=$(netstat -rn | while read a b rest ; do [ a = "0.0.0.0" ] || continue ; echo $b ; break ; done )
```

is rather more robust, but obviously longer.